# What's the character code for exclamation mark in circle?

Tags: unicode, character, symbols, non-ascii-characters

What's the Unicode or Segoe UI Symbols (or other font) code for exclamation mark in circle?

[image]

Answer (score 22):

There is no single Unicode codepoint for that particular symbol.

Unicode does define a `U+20DD COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE` codepoint, but most fonts (including Segoe) do not treat it as a combining symbol, but rather as its own character.  In Word, for instance, you would have to adjust the character spacing between it and a preceding character (in this case `U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK`) to a negative offset to make them overlap (see [Using the “Combining Enclosing Circle” character in Word](https://superuser.com/questions/312966/)).

*Some* fonts do support `U+20DD` in general (see [COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE (U+20DD) Font Support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20dd/fontsupport.htm)), and *some* of them do treat it as a combining mark (Code2000, GNU FreeFont fonts, STIX fonts, Symbola, XITS, etc), but the resulting overlap may not visually be exactly what you are looking for, depending on the size and alignment of the character it is being combined with.

Comment: in other words try "!\u20DD"

Comment: Looks like this, in case you want to copy/paste: `!&#x20DD;`    !⃝

Comment: Alternative also is `&#9888;`, which is exlcamation with triangle, not circle